# A group presentation given by the Collatz sequence of a fixed $n$. Has this been studied before?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, collatz-conjecture

*This is a [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request) question.*

### The Set Up:

Fix $n\in\Bbb N$.

Suppose

$$C(x)=\begin{cases}
x/2&:x\text{ is even},\\
3x+1&:x\text{ is odd}.
\end{cases}$$

Let $m\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$. Denote by $a^{(n)}_m$ the number $C^m(n)$.

Let $\left(p^{(n)}_j\right)_{j\in J}$ be all the prime divisors of all the $a^{(n)}_m$, in increasing order.

For example, if $n=11$, then

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
i & a^{(n)}_i & \text{Prime divisors of }a_i^{(n)}\\
\hline
0 & 11 & 11\\
1 & 34 & 2,17\\
2 & 17 & 17\\
3 & 52 & 2, 2, 13\\
4 & 26 & 2, 13\\
5 & 13 & 13\\
6 & 40 & 2, 2, 2, 5\\
7 & 20 & 2, 2, 5\\
8 & 10 & 2, 5\\
9 & 5 & 5\\
10 & 16 & 2,2,2,2\\
12 & 8 & 2,2,2\\
13 & 4 & 2, 2\\
14 & 2 & 2\\
15 & 1 & \text{n/a}
\end{array}.$$

Then $\left(p^{(11)}_j\right)_{j\in J}=(2, 5, 11, 13, 17)$.

Consider the group presentation

$$P(n):=\left\langle \left(p^{(n)}_j\right)_{j\in J} \,\middle |\, \left(a_m^{(n)}\right)_{m\in M}\right\rangle,$$

where each $a_m^{(n)}$ is written in its standard decomposition into primes, in ascending order.

For example,

$$\begin{align}
P(11)&=\langle 2, 5, 11, 13, 17\mid 11, 2\cdot 17, 17, 2^2\cdot 13, 2\cdot 13, 13, 2^3\cdot 5, 2^2\cdot 5, 2\cdot 5, 5, 2^4, 2^3, 2^2, 2\rangle\\
&\cong E,
\end{align}$$

where $E$ is the trivial group.

### The Question:

> Has $P(n)$ been studied before? If so, where?

### Thoughts:

This sort of thing is difficult to search for, not least because of the vast amount of material on the Collatz Conjecture.

My suspicion is that the group defined by the presentation is trivial for "most" $n\in\Bbb N$.

It looks like $P(n)$ lends itself well to experimentation in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/).

### Another Example:

$$\begin{align}
P(21)&=\langle 2, 3, 7\mid 3\cdot 7, 2^6, 2^5, 2^4, 2^3, 2^2, 2\rangle\\
&=\langle 3, 7\mid 3\cdot 7\rangle \\
&=\langle 3\mid \rangle\\
&\cong\Bbb Z.
\end{align}$$

Please help :)

Comment: It has just occurred to me that there's nothing special about the Collatz function here. That is, we can let $a_m$ be any sequence of natural numbers and $p_j$ the prime divisors.

Comment: I am not an expert with this kind of groups. It surely would help to know the criterion when such a group is the trivial group.

Comment: The process of determining whether a group given by a presentation is trivial is undecidable, @Peter.

Comment: What is the group operation on these groups you give presentations for?

Comment: I have used $\cdot$ in place of the standard concatenation (which would have been confusing). The numbers are not seen as numbers in the presentation, @Thissitehasbecomeadump., but, rather, abstract symbols.

Comment: Lagarias and others proved a weakened form of the conjecture using something called the $3x+1$ or wild semigroup. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3x_%2B_1_semigroup which is perhaps similar. I believe the analysis builds upon automata which essentially store the numbers being iterated upon within exponents. I don't recall a better example but the topic is covered broadly here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory